# How do I resubmit a podcast to iTunes after Apple has rejected it once?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, app-store-connect

Apple rejected my initial podcast submission but their rejection wasn't particularly informative.

The email I got from iTunes is the following

> Dear podcast owner,
>
> The following podcast has not been included in the iTunes podcast directory.
>
> Name: The Bottom :: Radio Breakout Feed URL: http://www.radiobreakout.com.au/podcast?podcast=thebottom
>
> Submissions may not be included in the directory for a variety of reasons. For more information, please see the podcast technical specification at http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/techspecs.html.
>
> Regards,
>
> The iTunes Store team

I can't see any errors; it is a valid RSS/XML feed. When I added it manually to iTunes it downloaded and played the show correctly so the feed does work.

The feed is available at:

http://www.radiobreakout.com.au/podcast?podcast=thebottom

I've updated the feed slightly since trying to submit the podcast and I'd like to try again but I cannot see how to resubmit the podcast once it has been rejected. Is this possible? If so, can someone walk me through the resubmission process?

Comment: Pardon the bluntness, but what exactly are we supposed to do about it? Feed Validators do agree that it's valid, it seems like your media is accessible, I'm sure you've done equally as much checking or more. What exactly are you asking us to do/help with?

Comment: Try putting a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: I'm sure, in here, is a specific question that can be answered on Ask Different, we just need to figure it out. I've put this on hold for the time being. Remember: no one here is an Apple employee or can speak on Apple's behalf. So questions need to be formatted such that a non-Apple insider can have a chance at helping you.

Comment: Yeah but sadly @IanC. not even I understand what Apple is meaning with that email they sent me. I have explained it the best I can - This is a forum for Apple users. So the question does not need to be answered by Apple I just want to know more info about this issue because I have ticket all the boxes I believe - I can't even re-submit the podcast because when I do it says it has already been submitted.

Comment: It sounds like the right question to ask, right now, is succinctly: How do I resubmit my podcast to iTunes after an initial rejection? -- why don't we clean it up and make that the question for now? If you have follow-on questions we'll use new questions on Ask Different to ask them. Sound good? I've made an edit to it -- what do you think? If it's agreeable I'll clean up these comments and release the hold.

Comment: sure sounds good to me

Answer (score 1):

The RSS has an invalid '.' at the end of it

`</channel>.`

fix that and it should be ok